# Why is Atom behaving like this?

Tags: windows, atom-editor, visual-glitch, asus

whenever I hover over other items the appearance of atom worsens. A pic is attached here . Please help [The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg3uS.jpg)

Not only the software atom, but Epic games also shows the same problem. The video of it is attached [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/r7dBvCiPsa881zhcA)

In addition to that, there is one more application thats behaving like this. I dont even know whats this problem actually called. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the graphics drivers were not setup correctly. Now that I have reset the settings, everything works just fine and the white lines have disappeared from everywhere.